# Creating a new column in a pandas df by matching an existing column to a dictionary key tuple index, and taking a value from a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

Say I have a pandas df of dogs and need to match them with a dictionary of them and their owners read from an XML file.

**dogsDF**

| Dog Name | Dog Type |
| --- | --- |
| Larry | Shihtzu |
| Shelly | Black Lab |
| Koda | Husky |

dogOwners = {('Larry', 'Shihtzu') : {'Weight(lbs)' : 15, 'Owner' : 'Shawn' 'Medication(per day)' : 2}, ('Shelly', 'Black Lab') : {'Weight(lbs)' : 67, 'Owner' : 'Mark'}, ('Koda', 'Husky') : {'Weight(lbs)' : 82, 'Owner' : 'Laura', 'Medication(per day)' : 1}}

**dogsDF**

| Dog Name | Dog Type | Owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Larry | Shihtzu | Shawn |
| Shelly | Black Lab | Mark |
| Koda | Husky | Laura |

If the format of the dictionary should be changed, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks for any help!

I've already tried:
dogsDF['Owner'] = dogsDF['Dog Name'].apply(lambda x : dogOwners.get(x)).fillna('')

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dictionary to `DataFrame` with help of [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
tmp = (pd.json_normalize(dogOwners.values())
         .set_axis(dogOwners.keys())
         .rename_axis(['Dog Name', 'Dog Type'])
      )

out = pd.merge(df, tmp, on=['Dog Name', 'Dog Type'])
```

Output:

```
  Dog Name   Dog Type  Weight(lbs)  Owner  Medication(per day)
0    Larry    Shihtzu           15  Shawn                  2.0
1   Shelly  Black Lab           67   Mark                  NaN
2     Koda      Husky           82  Laura                  1.0
```

You can filter the columns to use:

```
out = pd.merge(df, tmp[['Owner']], on=['Dog Name', 'Dog Type'])
```

Output:

```
  Dog Name   Dog Type  Owner
0    Larry    Shihtzu  Shawn
1   Shelly  Black Lab   Mark
2     Koda      Husky  Laura
```

A better format for your data might be a list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'Dog Name': 'Larry', 'Dog Type': 'Shihtzu', 'Weight(lbs)': 15, 'Owner': 'Shawn', 'Medication(per day)': 2.0},
       {'Dog Name': 'Shelly', 'Dog Type': 'Black Lab', 'Weight(lbs)': 67, 'Owner': 'Mark'},
       {'Dog Name': 'Koda', 'Dog Type': 'Husky', 'Weight(lbs)': 82, 'Owner': 'Laura', 'Medication(per day)': 1.0},
       ]

tmp = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `dogOwners.get(x)` doesn't work because your dictionary key is the dog name and type. And then 'Owner' is a key of that dictionary, but you can accomplish what you want using your current dictionary structure.

Reproducible example:

```
dogOwners = {('Larry', 'Shihtzu') : {'Weight(lbs)' : 15, 'Owner' : 'Shawn', 'Medication(per day)' : 2}, ('Shelly', 'Black Lab') : {'Weight(lbs)' : 67, 'Owner' : 'Mark'}, ('Koda', 'Husky') : {'Weight(lbs)' : 82, 'Owner' : 'Laura', 'Medication(per day)' : 1}}

dogsdict = {'Dog Name':['Larry', 'Shelly', 'Koda'], 'Dog Type':['Shihtzu', 'Black Lab', 'Husky']}

dogsDF = pd.DataFrame(dogsdict)

dogsDF['Owner'] = dogsDF.apply(lambda row: dogOwners.get((row["Dog Name"], row["Dog Type"]),"")['Owner'], axis=1)
```

BTW, the second argument in `.get()` will automatically return "" if the key doesn't exist, so you can skip the `.fillna()`

Hope that helps!